# Shell Script to test the output and create a new continue name

Tags: linux, shell, file, continue

I need help on how to create another continue file from my test results.

Example: after I run a command I got the below output

```
file001
file002
file003
```

So, I need the script create a next file name `file004`.

Comment: Hi, please share the script you have written so far

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: What is fixed? Can you use something like ``num=${f//file}; printf "file%03d\n" $(( num + 1 )) ?

Answer (score 0):

Perl can increment a string easily:

```
perl -e '$f = shift; print ++$f' file003
```

Answer (score 0):

Using perl as said above, you can do this:

```
perl -e '$f = shift; print ++$f' `ls | grep file| tail -1`
```

Comment: Hi ;   Thanks for the feedback, what actually I need  is let say i run vgs command . and the output show vol01 , vol_test01,vol_test02 and volvg. so I need to test if the vol_test vg already exist or not , if not create then create a new vg name call vol_test01 and if already exist then create continues number like vol_test03.    Thanks

Comment: @BangauPutih: Please, help us to help you. Try to ask a question we can answer: see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).